# Can't extend from AudioEffect

Tags: android, audio, effects

I'm trying to create a custom audio effect by extending from the class **android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect** but for some reason the constructor for this class is not presenting the same signature I see in the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.java?av=f).

The **AudioEffect** class doesn't seem to have some of the **public static final UUID** constants that define each different effect, for example like the following:

```
public static final UUID EFFECT_TYPE_BASS_BOOST = UUID
              .fromString("0634f220-ddd4-11db-a0fc-0002a5d5c51b");
```

I'm using the SDK for **API 10** (**v2.3.3**) which should work since every out-of-the-box effect that exists in android extends from this class.

```
public class BassBoost extends AudioEffect {
        ...
    public BassBoost(int priority, int audioSession)
        throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException,
           UnsupportedOperationException, RuntimeException {
        super(EFFECT_TYPE_BASS_BOOST, EFFECT_TYPE_NULL, priority, audioSession);

        int[] value = new int[1];
        checkStatus(getParameter(PARAM_STRENGTH_SUPPORTED, value));
        mStrengthSupported = (value[0] != 0);
    }
        ...
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you get success with the implementation of Bass effect in Music ?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I wasn't trying to implement the BassBoost effect but a custome one. In the question I was wondering why I couldn't extend from the AudioEffect class from Android's API, and that's because it marked as hidden like the answer states, so I wasn't able to take this approach to implement the effect.

Comment: BassBoost is the custom one. Anyway, i have try many to imlement Bassboost but not getting any effect. Do you know how to implement that effect in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `@hide` annotations those constants are not available in the public sdk api.

Comment: Aaah, that's an excellent and accurate answer, the constructor has the same annotation as well. I guess I'll have to look for alternatives then. Thanks!

Comment: @iDroidExplorer use the `BassBoost` class from the SDK